# Why is 'int' used as just int and why not as std::int in C++?

Tags: c++, std, standards

Unlike everything is `standard`ized in current C++, are there any specific reasons to leave `int`, `char`, ...., `main()` and others from it. (Not talking of `+`,`-`,`%`,.. because they aren't language-specific)

Why is it not like:

```
std::int std::main(std::int argc, std::char *argv[])
{
    //Sample C++ code (incorrect with current standards though)
    std::return 0;
}
```

Isn't standardization incomplete with them out of std scope?

What I believe is, they are basic components which occurs everywhere when writing a program, whether simple or complex. They are not included in the standardization, just to follow the **DRY** principle.

Comment: There's also the fact they come from C

Comment: Your question itself has the answer.

Comment: The `std` namespace contains the standard library. The language itself (including `int` and all the other primitive types and all syntactic constructs like `return` or `for`) is not defined inside the library. You can use C++ without using anything in `std`.

Comment: `std` is just a namespace. It would make equally little sense to start putting keywords in a namespace. `std::for(...)`?

Comment: @super What are `int`, `return`, etc, if not keywords?

Comment: @super in fact, following this logic, `std` should be in `std`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keywords such as `int` and `return` and the `main()` function are all included in [the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents). `std` does not mean that only those things are standardized. Instead, it refers to the things that are in the standard library (which, like keywords, is a part of the standard). Include files such as `#include <vector>` are needed to use the standard library, but keywords can be used without any `#include`s.

Comment: But it doesn't include everything that is standardized, like language specifications. That's what @vll means

Answer (score 11):

`std::` is the namespace name of the Standard Library. But C++ has built-in types, and those are more fundamental. In fact, significant parts of the Standard Library are built using types like `int`. You can see the chicken-and-egg problem if the Standard Library would depend on itself.

Answer (score 3):

The types you mention are *keywords*. Keywords are not identifiers and therefore cannot belong to scopes or namespaces.   During parsing of the program , keywords are found at an earlier stage than identifiers.

Changing the namespace of the program entry point (`::main` currently) would mean all linkers everywhere have to be updated and so I doubt there would be any support for such a move. Also it would go against the principle that `std` is for the standard library and not for user code, whereas the user writes the code that goes in `main`.

Comment: Using `std::main` instead of `main` would require changing the startup code (the assembly code that actually gets run by the OS, and calls `main`); it would generally not require any linker changes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. Int is a primitive (primary) data type. Primary data types are already defined in the programming languages also called primitive or in-built data types. "int" data type is one of them. In some of the languages, you can see some of the byte, short, int, long, char, float, double or boolean keywords used as themselves.

Hope I was helpful.